# Nginx not serving static files and user uploaded files in Django Kubernetes

Tags: django, nginx, kubernetes, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi i am working on a kubernetes and can't get static files or user documents. This runs behind nginx ingress all queries and django works as expected. But unable to figure out why images and other documents cant be obtained via url. Application gets installed using helm charts and functionality seems to be okay other than serving files.

```
FROM python:3.8.12-alpine3.15

ADD ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt


RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps postgresql-dev build-base linux-headers jpeg-dev zlib-dev\
    && python -m venv /env \
    && /env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip \
    && /env/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt \
    && runDeps="$(scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /env \
        | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r apk info --installed \
        | sort -u)" \
    && apk add --virtual rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps

ADD ./ /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

RUN apk add nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf
COPY helm/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "helm/run.sh"]
```

run.sh

```
nginx -g 'daemon on;'
gunicorn  main_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers 3
```

nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    upstream django {
        server 0.0.0.0:8080;
    }

    server {

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        listen 8000;

        location /static {
            autoindex on;
            alias /app/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }


        location /uploads{
            autoindex on;
             alias /app/uploads/;
         }

        # location ~* ^/[^/]+\.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|pdf)$ {
        #     root /app/;
        #     try_files $uri =404;;;;
        # }




    }
}
```

Django settings file is like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# media folder setting
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'uploads'
```

If i go to /admin url files are served but i get this error in a js file:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was one hell of a ride to figure it out. following changes in nginx.conf worked.

```
location your_ingresspath_here/static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /app/static/;
}
```